# Python - created exe file using pyinstaller keeps on crashing with error provided

Tags: python, ipython, pyinstaller

I'm importing an hl7apy module to the script it looks like it is looking for some files but not sure how to get all those. I'm attaching the code I have, it's in .ipynb but converted to .py using ipython nbconvert --to script .\Covid.ipynb then ran the command pyinstaller --debug-all .\Covid.py. The executable file gets generated however when I run the exe file it throws the error below.

Please advise. Thank you.

**ipynb code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from hl7apy.core import Message
from hl7apy.parser import parse_message
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

df = pd.read_csv(filename)

df['RACE'] = df[['RACE_AMERICAN_INDIAN_AK_NATIVE','RACE_ASIAN','RACE_BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN'
                 ,'RACE_NTV_HAWAIIAN_PACIFIC_ISL','RACE_WHITE','RACE_OTHER']].apply(lambda x: "".join(x.dropna()), axis=1)

df.drop(columns=['RACE_AMERICAN_INDIAN_AK_NATIVE','RACE_ASIAN','RACE_BLACK_AFRICAN_AMERICAN'
                 ,'RACE_NTV_HAWAIIAN_PACIFIC_ISL','RACE_WHITE','RACE_OTHER'], inplace=True)

df['ADMINISTERED_TIME'] = df['ADMINISTERED_TIME'].fillna('00:00')

df_covid = df.copy()

m = Message("VXU_V04")

from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
dt_msg = today.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

for index, row in df_covid.iterrows():

    #MSH
    m.msh.msh_3 = 'IS'
    m.msh.msh_4 = '77777'
    m.msh.msh_5 = 'Receiving Application'
    m.msh.msh_7 = str(dt_msg)
    m.msh.msh_9 = 'VXU^V04^VXU_V04'
    
    #PID
    m.pid.pid_1 = '1'
    m.pid.pid_3 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['PARTICIPANT_ID']) + '^^^^MRN^'
    m.pid.pid_5 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['LAST_NAME']) + '^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['FIRST_NAME'])            
    m.pid.pid_7 = datetime.strptime(df_covid.iloc[index]['BIRTH_DATE'],'%m/%d/%Y 0:00').strftime("%Y%m%d")
    m.pid.pid_8 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['GENDER'])
    m.pid.pid_10 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['RACE'])
    m.pid.pid_11 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ADDRESS1']) + '^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ADDRESS2']) +'^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['CITY']) + '^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['STATE']) + '^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ZIP']) + '^USA'                                                 
        
    
    #ORC
    m.orc.orc_1 = 'RE'
    m.orc.orc_9 = str(dt_msg)
    m.orc.orc_10 = '^' + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ADMINISTERED_BY'])
    m.orc.orc_11 = 'RXA'
    m.orc.orc_12 = '0'
    m.orc.orc_13 = '1'
    
    #OBX
    m.obx.obx_3 = '64994-7'
    
    #RXA
    m.rxa.rxa_1 = '0'
    m.rxa.rxa_2 = '1'
    m.rxa.rxa_3 = datetime.strptime(str(df_covid.iloc[index]['DOSE_ADMINISTERED_DATE']) + ' '
                                    + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ADMINISTERED_TIME']),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    m.rxa.rxa_4 = datetime.strptime(str(df_covid.iloc[index]['DOSE_ADMINISTERED_DATE']) + ' '
                                    + str(df_covid.iloc[index]['ADMINISTERED_TIME']),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M").strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    m.rxa.rxa_5 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['CVX_CODE'])
    m.rxa.rxa_9 = '00'
    m.rxa.rxa_11 = '77777'
    m.rxa.rxa_15 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['LOT'])
    m.rxa.rxa_17 = str(df_covid.iloc[index]['MANUFACTURER'])
    m.rxa.rxa_21 = 'A'
        
    df_covid.loc[index,'Hl7'] = m.to_er7().replace('\r','\n')
        
    with open(str(index) + '_some_file.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(m.to_er7().replace('\r','\n'))
        f.close()
```

**error**

```
 File "C:\Users\user\DataNow\COVID-19\Covid.py", line 9, in <module>
    from hl7apy.core import Message
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "hl7apy\__init__.py", line 332, in <module>
  File "hl7apy\__init__.py", line 329, in _discover_libraries
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI209722\\hl7apy'
[28568] Failed to execute script Covid
```

Comment: it seems it didn't find all elements needed by `hl7apy` and it didn't add this to .exe - and you may have to manually add information to configuration file created by pyinstaller.

Comment: Thank you for that information, what are the the steps to manually add it and I'm guessing I should already have those elements where should I look for that.

Comment: error show problem with `_discover_libraries` and you can see this in [source code](https://github.com/crs4/hl7apy/blob/develop/hl7apy/__init__.py) - it seems it add some other folder in non-standard way and probably didn't recognized it and it couldn't add it to .exe You may have to add module `h17apy` to your project manually .

Comment: somewhere in pyinstaller documentation you can find page wiht name similar to  "What to do if it doesn't work"

Comment: pyinstalle doc: [When Things Go Wrong](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html) and one of subject [Helping PyInstaller Find Modules](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules)

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I went through the documents and ended up running pyinstaller --hidden-imports=hl7apy.* and copying all the needed file to the dist folder.

Answer (score 0):

HL7apy references the modules folder structure during the execution of the module, hence the directories need to be included with pyinstaller.

Just use the --add-data option to include the hl7apy folder in the executable

```bash
pyinstaller main.py --name main --add-data c:\programming\main\env\Lib\site-packages\hl7apy:hl7apy
```